# springmvc DeferredResult .. "No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity$DefaultBuilder"

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

This works okay:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Foo> _findOne(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Foo foo = findOne(id);
    if (foo == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Foo>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Foo>(foo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The asynchronous version fails when trying an error due to no items)

Server exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity$DefaultBuilder
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Here is DeferredResult version

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/foos/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Foo>> _findOne(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Foo>> deferred = new DeferredResult<>();
    findOne(id).singleOrDefault(null).timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(item -> {
                        if (item == null) {
                            deferred.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
                        } else {
                            deferred.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(item));
                        }
                    }, t -> {
                        deferred.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                    }
            );
    return deferred;
}
```

I've read [Spring Boot Application: No converter found for return value of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832735/spring-boot-application-no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type) but I think my case is different as it is only when I return a NOT_FOUND

Comment: What do you have <mvc:message-converters> defined in spring config & do  you have required jackson dependencies in pom.xml ?

Comment: I know that question I linked to mentioned  <mvc:message-converters> but I do not have it. Weirdly I did not need it with the non-deferred version. And I dont even (currently) have a mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530045/406-status-on-response-when-invoking-seterrorresult-on-deferredresult) and [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/async/DeferredResultController.java) 
I see deferred.setErrorResult **needs** a exception so I now have:

```
deferred.setErrorResult(new FooNotFoundException());
```

where:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
static class FooNotFoundException extends Exception {
}
```

Keeping this question rather than deleting it as the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` not in the linked SO question and was quite confusing.